# Implementing a custom Angular service that uses $location and $emit

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to register a custom service in Angularjs that gets the URL, and then emits it back up to the higher level controller. I have 1. Registered the service with app.service 2. Passed in the name of the service to the lower controller 3. Am listening for the change in the higher level controller. I have it working when I duplicate the function in each controller, but I'm trying to refactor.

**module.js** registers the service

```js
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngRoute']);
app.service('changedUrlService', function() {
    this.getUrl = function(url) {
        $scope.emit('urlChange', url);
    }
});
```

**lowerController.js** controller that uses the service

```js
angular.module('demo').controller("lowerController", ['$scope', '$http','$location' 'changedUrlService', function ($scope, $http, $location, changedUrlService)
{
  $scope.url = $location.url();
  $scope.findUrl = changedUrlService.getUrl($scope.url);
  $scope.findUrl();
}
```

**higherController.js** listening for the emit

```js
$scope.$on('urlChange', function (event, item) {
  $scope.myUrl = item;
  console.log($scope.myUrl);
});
```

I have received a variety of errors as I tweaked this, including Unknown Provider, $scope not defined and more.

Comment: for your changedUrlService, you will need to inject in $rootScope

Comment: I believe I tried something similar, do you mean into the service?

Comment: Yes. in your service, $scope is undefined (the unknown provider error you are receiving) so you will need to inject the applications $rootScope. Then you can emit like you are after you inject $rootScope into your service (changedUrlService)

Comment: like so? 
    app.service('changedUrlService', '$rootScope', function($rootScope) {
        this.getUrl = function(url) {
        $scope.emit('urlChange', url);
        }
    });

Comment: you're missing the dependency array.
app.service('changedUrlService', ['$rootScope', function($rootScope) { this.getUrl = function(url) { $scope.emit('urlChange', url); } }]);Note the two brackets [...]

Answer (score 0):

If you see this below code, you will understand you have not injected anything to the service. First you need to inject any other service and then only you can use it. But service is not the correct place to inject $scope.

```
var app = angular.module('demo', ['ngRoute']);
app.service('changedUrlService', function() { // No dependencies injected
    this.getUrl = function(url) {
        $scope.emit('urlChange', url); // Incorrect
    }
});
```

What you can do is, return the string from the string. Inject this service changedUrlService into the controller and use this to get the string. And not from the controller call the emit function.

Please let me know if it helps.

Comment: So where does it get injected? I'm not following the "return the string from the string" either.